re-entering the UK after code 3 stamp
My situation:
I have two nationalities, one of them is visa free. I was on a tier 4 student visa (associated to the non-visa-free passport), which got canceled when I took an interuption of studies. I missed the email informing me that my residence permit(BRP) was canceled. So I tried to re-enter the UK with the BRP to visit some friends on the 7th of June. They stoped and questioned me, and I immediately switched the visa-free passport and stated that my purpose was to vist friend. They questioned me and gave a code 3 stamp, 6 months leave to enter. The IO told me that this is a warning, and I might get questioned if I attempt to re-enter the UK. I stayed in the UK for 1 week before I left. 
Question:

Am I flagged in their system forever? To what extent will they record detail of this 'warning' and how will this be used against me in the future?

I plan to go to the UK for a week and visit my friends again in early august, if I try to enter with the visa free passport what are the chances that they refuse my entry?

If they refuse entry and place a ban on the visa free passport, does it affect the appliccation to the new student visa on the other passport?


I'm really worried, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

AFAIK Code 3 status means the IO had concerns you weren’t a genuine visitor but landed you anyway. There’s a record on the system and you can probably expect to be questioned next time you try to visit. Returning so soon isn’t a great idea IMHO, best make sure you have documentary evidence to prove you meet the UK’s Immigration Rules eg proof of ties to home country.

I'd stay out of the UK for now until you get your new student visa. In fact, I'd enlist a solicitor specialised in UK immigration law if I were you as I'm not convinced getting a new student visa will be problem-free for you since you've abandoned your studies without notifying the Home Office. That could be seen as fraud even if it wasn't intended as such.
Bans are tied to a person, NOT a passport, so again, don't test the Border Force, as they'll have ZERO qualms about imposing a ban if they feel reasonably convinced of any foul play on your part (whether true or not)
